# Checking the equality of different kind of functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, equality, typeof

```
function a(){ return true; }
var b = function(){ return true; };
window.c = function(){ return true; };


console.log(typeof a);//returns funtion
console.log(typeof b);  //returns funtion
console.log(typeof window.c);   //returns funtion

typeof a === typeof b === typeof window.c  //returns false
```

On running the above code in the console , the final statement gives false. whereas, typeof all the 3 functions returns function. I know that there are some weird parts in javascript with typeof ..Can you guys explain this please..

Comment: **Answer:** `true === typeof window.c` is `false`.

Comment: ```typeof a === typeof b``` is evaluated to ```true```.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the types not being equal but the fact that:

```
a === b === c
```

is interpreted as:

```
(a === b) === c
```

So this means that the first test `typeof a === typeof b` is resolved as `true` and now you perform an equality check like `true === typeof window.c`.

You can solve the problem by rewriting the condition to:

```
(typeof a === typeof b) && (typeof b === typeof window.c)
```

Comment: `(a === b) ==== c`, huh? 4 `=`. That's new to me.

Comment: @Tushar: thanks for spotting. That was indeed a typo. Many thanks.